# Nginx location　/var/www/html/side/a/index.html -> example.com/a/index.html

Tags: nginx

ディレクトリ`side`があるにも関わらず、その`side`をURLでは省くにはどうすればよいでしょうか。
301リダイレクトではSEO的に複雑なので、そのままNginxで設定したいです。

例

```
/var/www/html/side/a/index.html
```

実際

```
example.com/side/a/index.html
```

理想

```
example.com/a/index.html
```

実際に試した構文

```
location /side/*/ {
    index index.html;
    root /var/www/html/side;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` の `root` を `/var/www/html/side` にすれば良いように見えますがどうでしょうか。

```
location / {
    index index.html;
    root /var/www/html/side;
}
```

Comment: エスパーすると、`/var/www/html/abc.html`にはは`/abc.html`としてアクセスさせたい、`/var/www/html/side/def.html`も`/def.html`としてアクセスさせたい、って話だと想像しました。

Comment: `/var/www/html/index.html`は`example.com`です。`/var/www/html/side/abc/index.html`は`example.com/abc`にしたいです。